# Is there a way to prevent saved authentication in Tortoise SVN at the Server level?

Tags: authentication, svn, tortoise-svn

I am using Tortoise SVN on my Window server and I am trying to not have a username/password stored. I was able to figure out that if I make changes to `%appdata%\Subversion\config` enabling:

```
store-passwords = no
store-auth-creds = no
```

but this is at the user level.

I would like to apply this but at the server level how can I do that? When I make the same changes to the `servers.config` file - `%appdata%\Subversion\servers` - rhe changes would not apply. Any reason why? Am I missing a step here?

I apply the changes below to the `servers.config` file:

```
store-passwords = no 
store-auth-creds = no
store-plaintext-passwords = no
```

I would like to apply these changes at the server level so that any user that tries to save their credentials with Tortoise SVN and disable the save option for all users.

Comment: Are you sure the server is using that configuration file?

Comment: Yes when I make the changes to the Config file it would work just for the user I make the changes to but when I try to apply the same thing for Servers.config file which should effect the whole server it will not apply. How can I make sure that I am using the servers and config file in the server?

Comment: There should be a server log of some kind that cords which configuration is being loaded when the server application starts.

Answer (score 1):

No, that's not possible. Subversion Server has no control over the client operation, how it stores and presents credentials and so on.

Besides that, even if you manage to restrict TortoiseSVN somehow (ex. by setting up restrictions on the client operating system), other SVN clients exist, which have their own settings. User can simply use another client, like the `svn` tool (the official Subversion client) to bypass your restrictions. That client also includes `--config-dir` option to use another location for config files, so the attempt lock its default configuration directory won't help.

You have to re-think your approach at security. It is really annoying thing to do to enter credentials every time you sync with the repository, provided you sync often, as per modern development recommendations; there **must** be some mechanism which makes this easier and puts less burden on the user. For example, SVN over SSH can [use SSH key-based authentication](https://tortoisesvn.net/ssh_howto.html) and key agents; SVN over HTTPS is able to use [client certificate authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2337184/commit-via-svn-and-client-certificate) (not sure about Tortoise supports it) and so on.